# SQL Transaction using Apache Spark and Scala

Tags: sql, scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, sqltransaction

With a data frame of IPs and updated status, we first need to delete the data frame's IPs from the SQL table. After that, we should insert this data frame with the updated status using Spark SQL. Additionally, the transaction should roll back if either the deletion or insertion encounters an error. I am stuck with various solutions; if you can suggest an optimal way of doing it, it would be of great help

```scala
val connection = DriverManager.getConnection(jdbcUrl, "user", "Password")
    val statement = connection.createStatement()

    try {

      connection.setAutoCommit(false)

       //Build the DELETE SQL statement
      val deleteStatement =
        s"""
           |DELETE FROM test_logs1
           |WHERE IPAddress IN (${ipList.map(ip => s"'$ip'").mkString(",")})
       """.stripMargin

       //Execute the DELETE statement
      statement.execute(deleteStatement)

      println("df_to_insert after deletion:")
      df_to_insert.show()
      df_to_insert.write
        .mode("append")
        .jdbc(jdbcUrl, tableName, connectionProperties)

      statement.execute("COMMIT")
    
      connection.commit()


    }

    catch {
      case e: Exception =>

        // Rollback the transaction in case of an exception
        println("Error occurred: " + e.getMessage)
        connection.rollback()

    } finally {
      // Close the statement and connection
      if (statement != null) statement.close()
      if (connection != null) connection.close()
}
```

This gives me a lock-timeout, retry transaction  error

Answer (score 0):

Your `DELETE` statement and your `INSERT` ones via `df_to_insert.write` are not using the same connection (and transaction).

This likely explains the error you get as the `DELETE`s are not commited yet when you try to insert.

`df_to_insert.write` is opening its own connection/transaction.